# How can I download the build file from github actions?

Tags: github-actions

I want to know how can I download build file from Github Actions.
so the main problem is that, I am a windows user and I want to build my application for mac users. But there is no simple way of doing it so I used Github Actions to build the application for mac users. It ran successfully but how can I download the build file.
[Link to the Github Repo](https://github.com/simplycode07/SKYZoom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once built, you should first upload the release asset you just built, with the [`actions/upload-release-asset`](https://github.com/actions/upload-release-asset) GitHub Action.

You have a full example in "[Automated multi-platform releases with GitHub Actions](https://dev.to/eugenebabichenko/automated-multi-platform-releases-with-github-actions-1abg) " from [Yevhenii Babichenko](https://twitter.com/ybabichenko)

```yaml
# ...
  release_assets:
    name: Release assets
    needs: create_release # we need to know the upload URL
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }} # we run many different builds
    strategy:
      # just an example matrix
      matrix:
        config:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
          - os: macos-latest
          - os: windows-latest
    steps:
      # checkout of cource
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      # ... whatever build and packaging steps you need here
      # and finally do an upload!
      - name: Upload release assets
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ needs.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          # This is how it will be named on the release page. Put hatever name
          # you like, remember that they need to be different for each platform.
          # You can choose any build matrix parameters. For Rust I use the
          # target triple.
          asset_name: program-name-${{ matrix.config.os }}
          # The path to the file you want to upload.
          asset_path: ./path/to/your/file
          # probably you will need to change it, but most likely you are
          # uploading a binary file
          asset_content_type: application/octet-stream
```

Only when those assets are uploaded to GitHub, you can consider [downloading them](https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8#gistcomment-3561431).